# How do I convert a c-string into an array of pointers where each pointer is a word in the char array?

Tags: c++

// I have to input a line of text into a c-string and then convert each word into a pointer in an array of pointers.

// I can get the line of text using cin.get() but do not know how to proceed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

// Function Prototypes

void get_input(char *array, int size); // gets paragraph as input and assigns it to char array



int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 256; // holds size of char array

    const int POINTER_SIZE = 20; // holds 20 pointers in array of pointers

    char paragraph[SIZE]; // initialize array to hold paragraph

    get_input(paragraph, SIZE); 




}

// Function Definitions

void get_input(char *array, int size) {

    cout << "Enter a paragraph: ";

    cin.getline(array, size); 

}
```

// I need the line of input to be broken up into individual strings and stored as an array of pointers to each word.

Comment: OT: 256 is probably too small.

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot use std::string?

Comment: My instructor wants us to strictly use an array of pointers to access the individual words of the sentence.

Comment: You might want to look at `strtok`

Answer (score 0):

After reading the input into your array, you can iterate through the array, and setting a pointer to the first character of each word.

```
char* word[100];
// Assuming the first character is the beginning of a word
word[0] = &paragraph[0];

int c = 1;
int i = 1;
while(paragraph[i] != '\0'){
  // If the character was a letter
  if((paragraph[i] >= 65 && paragraph[i] <= 90) || (paragraph[i] >= 97 && paragraph[i] <= 122)){
    // If the previous character was not a letter
    if(!(paragraph[i-1] >= 65 && paragraph[i-1] <= 90) && !(paragraph[i-1] >= 97 && paragraph[i-1] <= 122)){
      word[c] = &paragraph[i];
      c++
    }
  }
    i++;
}
```

You can also use a vector of `char* arrays` to store the words and splice the words through non-letter characters and then generate a pointer for each item in the vector.

Answer (score -2):

you can use c_str() function to exchange

Comment: What would I be exchanging??

Comment: I assume Zachary is not permitted to use `std::string`. Even if `std::string` was permitted how does this answer help create an array of pointers to each word.

Comment: Correct. My instructor wants us to access each individual "word" in the paragraph by an array of pointers to those respective words.